# How to use Vector Layers on Website or App?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I had downloaded an [app UI kit](https://graphicriver.net/item/mobile-app-ui-kit/9926316) from Themeforest, it contains various .psd files like Sign in Page, chart, chat, weather, forms etc.. I want to use the components present in .psd file like gear icon, button or chart design but they are not available as images but probably as vector shapes.

[image]

As you can see, there are a couple of shapes, how to export them so I can use them on website or app?

Comment: You should probably avoid looking for PSDs, and avoid using Photoshop for vector work. Instead look for SVG icons. You can use these directly on web pages. You could even create your own SVG icons in Illustrator or Inskcape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use the right button to click on the layer and duplicate it in a new document
- Holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd> (Mac)/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (Win), click the layer thumbnail to load the transparency channel
- **Menu Image** > **Crop**
- **Menu File** > **Export** > **Save for web** > File format **PNG-24** with **Transparency** checked

[image: Vector to image]

[image: Star]

Comment: Is it possible to export them as SVG so they look same upon different zoom levels?

Comment: Editing them in Illustrator.